# Software to record and playback mouse movement/clicks and keyboard presses?

Tags: keyboard, applescript, automator, mouse, text-input

I was wondering if there was any software out there that could record mouse/keyboard input and allow you to play back the input that was made?

I've tried using Automator but for some reason it's not picking up all my input and when I play it back it does the wrong thing and gets into a mess. I've also tried using Systems Events in AppleScript but I can't get the "click" command to work at all.

Thanks!

Comment: To get the clicks working in applescript you will need to do GUI scripting. It can be tedious, but if you don't have that much to do it can be worth looking at.

Comment: Yea I tried to have a look at doing that (I downloaded UIBrowser to get the GUI element hierarchy) but I couldn't get it to do anything.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly. I could look into it and see how hard it would be.

Comment: I'm writing an app, and I want to test it regularly by running a script that interacts with the user interface in a particular, recorded way. That way I can be more sure that I haven't broken anything when I make a change.

Comment: @JamesBedford I think you can play with `Automator`, it's built into the OS, under Utilities. I think it can replay Keyboard and Mouse event if you record them into a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried out a whole ton of software for doing this, but Sikuli is now by far the best automation software I've come across.

It uses computer vision to automate any part of the GUI. For example, you can just take a small screenshot of the button you want to click on and paste it into your script and Sikuli will click on it. It also provides a series of really easy to use functions for automating keyboard input and mouse clicks. Plus, it uses Jython for its automation scripts so you can use Python or Java in your scripts too!

Really recommended. Here's a [link to their homepage](http://sikuli.org/).

Answer (score 3):

[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) supports both creating macros by recording them and recording and playing back temporary macros:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me [Auto Macro Recorder](http://www.readmesoft.com/mac/auto-macro-recorder-for-mac-os.htm)

I was searching for hours, and this one finally did the job for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.